# Scaling from the center of the object?

Tags: modeling, mesh, edges, selection-tools

[image: Center Setting?]

I'm trying to scale from the center. The entire circle is selected but it's scaling from the white edge that was option clicked. Is there a setting for this? How can I keep my selections centered?

Cheers!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change Pivot point to "bounding box center"

[image]